# Should we have a question regarding how to minimize the impact of Windows 10 reboots for updates on your workflow?

Tags: discussion

We sometimes get questions from Windows 10 users who are asking for help after their Windows 10 machine rebooted while they were away, leading to lost work. These users sometimes mention offhandedly that they're going to disable Windows Update after this to avoid it happening again. While this is definitely a solution, it's not really a pretty one because it can lead to compounding security issues.

Should we have a canonical question giving advice to users on how they can reduce the chance of such an incident happening again without taking such drastic steps as reducing device security? we can then reference this question when we get new questions like that.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Do you have question in mind that we can use as a starting point?